# Web Browser with Googple Map

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, google-maps

I am working on Desktop application C# .Net. On my form I am using Web Browser Control to open Google Map (Using API 3.0) Google map is showing perfectly but the problem is "Kilometer Scale" is showing blank.

I have a script file Map.html, showing below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>

<title>Google Maps</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false&libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var markersArray = [];

window.onload = function () 
{
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(29.99300, 68.99414);
    var options = 
    {
        zoom: 5,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scaleControl: true                
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("divmap"), options);
}

</script>    
</head>

<body>     
    <div id="divmap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and a windows form in Visual studio 2010. On form I have placed a Web Browser control and on form load code is given below:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String strMapPath = @"C:\WebBrowserWithGoogpleMap\Map.html";
    webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(strMapPath));
}
```

Please help, how to get rid from this problem.

Comment: Can't help you without any code

Answer (score 0):

This issue has just been answered in another question. It seems to be the fact that WPF WebBrowser uses an old version of IE.

See [scaleControl not displaying correctly in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042096/scalecontrol-not-displaying-correctly-in-net) for the answer given there